# Laravel-Excel column formatting replaces digit with 0

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

**Versions**

- PHP version: 7.1
- Laravel version: 5.4
- Package version: 2.1

**Description**

When exporting to an excel spreadsheet, column formatting is generating a rounded number.

**Steps to Reproduce**

*Expected behavior:*

Column with following format:

```
$sheet->setColumnFormat(
       array( 'C' => '0', //NUMBER format 
));
```

for a number like: 4444444444444444, it should reproduce the exact same number,

**Actual behavior:**

Instead, it is generating the following: 4444444444444440
It is replacing the last "4" with a "0".

**Additional Information**

By changing the format to "TEXT" or "General" the same happens and the number represent in scientific notation number: 4.44444E+15

[Reference for available column formatting](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/2.1/reference-guide/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

Not the ideal solution but it works fine.

```
$sheet->setCellValueExplicit('C'.$rowCount, $myData);
```

First I append all the data with the format I want to the row, and then I populate only the cell I need with explicit data using the method **setCellValueExplicit**. A little "hack", I would say.

Comment: where do you get $rowCount and $myData? please show me the entire file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are experiencing [15 digit precision](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/). Anything exceeding 15 digits will result in rounding.

Comment: It is definitely getting the issue when I change from 444444444444444 (length of 15) to 4444444444444444 (length of 16). The first one is reproduced correctly, while the the second is replaced with a 0 in the last digit.

Comment: Regarding the two solutions from your link: the first one recommends the use of the function ROUND. Is it possible to get Laravel-Excel to place functions into cells? The second solution would not be an option since I don't want people to do this change all the time.